# advanced options I2C not showing

Tags: raspi-config

why do you think the options under A6 are not showed? I need to enable the I2C options to use a LCD.  I DON'T understand what is happening.[image]

Comment: have you tried it from the preferences menu in the desktop?

Comment: i have totally forgot about that. Under raspi-config:advanced options:i2c is there only the option to enable the i2c or is there something else? I will tell you if the lcd works in a few minuts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I was completely wrong. [This answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63076/advanced-options-i2c-not-showing/63078?noredirect=1#68036) is correct.

You might be using an older version of raspi-config or something similar. Try selecting the "update" option and see if it shows the I2C enable option now. If not, the desktop application "Raspberry Pi Configuration" should definitely have it.

Comment: I don't understand why this is marked as the answer. He was looking in the wrong menu.

Comment: @88weighed I agree, but I can't delete my answer now. I'll edit to include a link to one of the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look under option 5, "Interfacing Options"
[image: A gif showing the raspi-config tool being used to enable I2C]

Answer (score 3):

I have the same options to choose from in `Advanced Settings` as in your picture, but in `5 Interfacing Options` I found the option `P5 I2C`

Maybe that helps someone.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

To enable I2C you need to do three things.

1. add the line `dtparam=i2c_arm=on` to `/boot/config.txt`
2. add the line `i2c-dev` to `/etc/modules`
3. reboot